# Why should the degree of freedom of the last row be k-1 not k

Tags: mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test

[image]

In the goodness of fit chi squared test, the proof as below shows 
the way how to compute chisquared distribution value(learned in elementary course, just how to compute without the speicific reason) is applied to chisquared distribution mathematically.

The proof is for special case : k row by 2 col

As you know, in this case, degree of freedom should be (k-1) * (2-1),
so it must be k-1.

my question is in this point, 
at the sight of last row of the proof, the degree of freedom of the last row 
should be k not k-1 because, it is the summation of standard normalized binomial distribution (quantity of "k" not "k-1)

i was wondering if you could let me know the reason why.

Thank you in advnace.

Comment: I don't see any claim of degrees of freedom being $k$ anywhere

Comment: Z^2 ~ Chi df:1 // Z^2 + Z^2 + Z^2 + ... + Z^2 quantity of "k" shoud be ~ Chi df:k. by CLT, as you see the last row is the summation of the squre of standard normalized binomial (Z^2) quantity of "k" should be "k"

Comment: http://www.randomservices.org/random/special/ChiSquare.html  like term 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the link you point to in comments refers to

> a sequence of independent standard normal variables

You don't have that here, because of the fact that $\hat{\theta}$ is estimated -- the deviations from $\hat{\theta}$ are dependent, since both the row and column totals of the $f$ terms in the $2\times k$ table sum to the same as the row and column totals of the $e$ terms (the expected values).

Under the model, this dependence is of exactly the form that would decrease the contribution of the $k$ degrees of freedom by $1$.